# UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification notification is not called on iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to detect when a user starts recording the screen and for that, I am adding observer for notification UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification. However UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification notification is working fine in simulator. How should I test the app by recording the screen?

Comment: If you hold down option key on your keyboard while the simulator is running, the snapshot button becomes a record button.

Comment: @Rob, this recording is not the same as done by iPhone so notification is not generated.

Comment: Yeah, you will have to test this on a physical device.